# Memory Leakage. Constantly rises until game crashes

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm new to android development and I'm having a problem regarding the memory used by my game. It constantly rises until it crashes. I would appreciate if you could help me. Thank you.

Also, regarding the Spritebatch do i need to call this.dispose in the java class where i extend to game for it to be disposed? If so where can i call it? Thank you

```
public class Zero implements Screen, InputProcessor {
    Pmacgame game;
    private Stage stage;
    private Skin skin;
    private Sound sound ,laser;
    private Music musicbg;
    private Sprite spritebg, playerImage;
    private ImageButton imgbtnLeft, imgbtnRight, fire, color1, color2, color3, color4,
                        bullet1, bullet2, bullet3, bullet4;
    public static final float fireDelay = 0.3f;
    String rr2;
    private static int o = 0;

    Rectangle player;
    ArrayList<Bullet> bullets;
    ArrayList<Target> targets;
    ArrayList<Explode> explodes;
    //long lastDrop;
    int score;
    boolean a, b;
    public static final float minSpawnTime = 0.5f;
    public static final float maxSpawnTime = 1.25f;
    float shootTimer, targetSpawnTimer;
    Random random;
    public static int select;
    public static int dis = 0;
    public float health = 1;
    private Sprite greenBar, redBar, blueBar, pinkBar, greenBarO, redBarO, blueBarO, pinkBarO;
    public Zero(Pmacgame game){



    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        shootTimer += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        ArrayList<Bullet> bulletsToRemove = new ArrayList<>();

            if (fire.isPressed() && shootTimer >= fireDelay) {
                shootTimer = 0;
                bullets.add(new Bullet(player.x + 32f));
            }


            for (Bullet bullet : bullets) {
                bullet.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
                if (bullet.remove)
                    bulletsToRemove.add(bullet);
            }

        targetSpawnTimer -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (targetSpawnTimer<=0){
            targetSpawnTimer = random.nextFloat() * (maxSpawnTime -minSpawnTime) + minSpawnTime;
            targets.add(new Target(MathUtils.random(267, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-350f)));
        }
        ArrayList<Target> targetsToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Target target: targets){
            target.update(delta);
            if (target.remove)
                targetsToRemove.add(target);
            if (target.getY()<=0){
                health -= 0.1f;
                if (health<=0){
                    select = 0;
                    dis = 1;
                    this.dispose();
                    game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(game, score));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }


        ArrayList<Explode> explodesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Explode explode: explodes){
            explode.update(delta);
            if (explode.remove)
                explodesToRemove.add(explode);
        }
        explodes.removeAll(explodesToRemove);

        for (Bullet bullet: bullets){
            for (Target target: targets){
                if (bullet.getCollisionRect().collidesWith(target.getCollisionRect())){

                    targetsToRemove.add(target);
                    bulletsToRemove.add(bullet);
                    score+=5;
                    explodes.add(new Explode(target.getX(), target.getY()));
                    sound.play(1f, 1.3f, 0f);
                }
            }
        }

        targets.removeAll(targetsToRemove);
        bullets.removeAll(bulletsToRemove);

        //Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        game.batch.begin();
        spritebg.draw(game.batch);
        game.batch.draw(blueBarO, 0, 575, blueBarO.getWidth(), blueBarO.getHeight());
        game.batch.draw(redBarO, 0, 550, redBarO.getWidth(), redBarO.getHeight());
        game.batch.draw(greenBarO, 0, 525, greenBarO.getWidth(), greenBarO.getHeight());
        game.batch.draw(pinkBarO, 0, 600, pinkBarO.getWidth(), pinkBarO.getHeight());
        game.font.draw(game.batch, "SCORE: " + score, 40, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 40 );
        for (Bullet bullet: bullets){
            bullet.render(game.batch);
        }
        for (Target target: targets){
            target.render(game.batch);
        }
        for (Explode explode: explodes){
            explode.render(game.batch);
        }
        if (health == 0) greenBar.setSize(greenBar.getWidth(), 0f);
        game.batch.draw(greenBar, 0, 525, greenBar.getWidth() * health, greenBar.getHeight());
        game.batch.draw(redBar, 0, 550, redBar.getWidth(), redBar.getHeight());
        game.batch.draw(blueBar, 0, 575, blueBar.getWidth(), blueBar.getHeight());
        game.batch.draw(pinkBar, 0, 600, pinkBar.getWidth(), pinkBar.getHeight());
        game.batch.draw(playerImage, player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
        game.batch.end();


        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
        if (a) player.x -= 450 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (b) player.x += 450 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (player.x < 65f + imgbtnLeft.getWidth() + imgbtnRight.getWidth())
            player.x = 65f + imgbtnLeft.getWidth() + imgbtnRight.getWidth();
        if (player.x > Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 350f)
            player.x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 350f;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        musicbg.dispose();
        laser.dispose();
        stage.dispose();
        skin.dispose();
        sound.dispose();

    }

}
```

```
public class Pmacgame extends Game {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    BitmapFont font;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("r.fnt"));

        this.setScreen(new Zero(this));


    }


    @Override
    public void render () {
        super.render();

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        font.dispose();
        batch.dispose();
    }


}
```

Comment: what are the data member of Bullet, Target, Explode class. Check is it worthy to create objects of those classes inside the render method. if object creation is frequent try to use pool API. container(Arraylist) creation inside the render method.  ??

Comment: Comment out new statements and check if memory leakage still happens. Un-comment them one  by one to find out problematic one. And, of course, as Aryan says, try not to allocate them inside render method (every frame), but at create method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reading between the lines, but it looks like you must be loading a Texture in the constructor of Bullet/Target/Explosion, since I don't see you passing a Texture or TextureRegion reference to their constructors or `render` methods.

You should be loading all your Textures in a single class and passing references to your game objects for them to "borrow" and draw with. Otherwise, you are loading many copies of the same images for no reason.

Also, a Texture is a Disposable, which means it uses native memory and must have `dispose()` called on it before you let the garbage collector take it. Otherwise, the native memory is leaked.

In your case, all these Bullets, Targets, and Explosions are loading many Textures over and over and never disposing them when you remove them.

Regarding your question about the SpriteBatch. Yes, you should dispose of it in the same class you instantiate it, and `dispose()` is the right place to do it.

**Edit, barebones example:**

```
public class Assets implements Disposable {

    public final Texture horse;
    public final Texture bullet;
    // etc.

    public Assets (){
        horse = new Texture("horse.png");
        //...
    }

    public void dispose(){
        horse.dispose();
        //...
    }
}

public class Zero implements Screen, InputProcessor {
    private final Assets assets;
    //...

    public Zero (){
        assets = new Assets();
        //...
    }

    //...

    public void dispose(){
        assets.dispose();
        //...
    }
}

public class Bullet {
    //...

    public void render(SpriteBatch batch, Assets assets){
         batch.render(assets.bullet, /*...*/);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right I'm loading textures inside their constructor. I'd really appreciate it if you can give me an example on using a single class for my textures then passing them through reference. Thank you.

Comment: @ZerOjMac I added an example. But you should also look into LibGDX's AssetManager class as it is a better way of handling assets than manually loading each one yourself. And after you understand how to use it, I suggest looking up the CoveTools library and using its AssignmentAssetManager to remove a ton of boilerplate code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, I'll be looking at those things you mentioned.

Comment: @ZerOjMac You're welcome. Also, one other unrelated thing I noticed... You create a number of new ArrayLists in your render loop. This can cause little stutters in the frame rate because it has to allocate the backing array of the ArrayList, possibly has to resize it as you fill it up (which means allocating a bigger array and copying the first), and then has to deallocate the backing array(s). I would suggest using final member fields for these lists so they are allocated only one time.

Comment: this may be kinda late but thanks to you I managed to develop my first game. It's still not done as I still have ideas but check it out.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pmac.full